# Regarding fragment transactions

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments

I am having three fragments in one activity and handled backpress in activity .On *back press* in one fragment `(CallingFragment)` it loads `DialerFragment` as I have added it to backstack while loading `CallingFragement` and giving this *logs*. Please tell me why it is happening?

**LOADING CALLING FRAGMENT:**

```
 void launchCallingFrag(String number, String name ,long time , boolean isongoing,String price )
    {
        String calleename= name;
        if(calleename==null)
        calleename=CommonUtility.getContactDisplayNameByNumber(number, context);

        callingScreenFragment.setNumber( number,calleename ,time,isongoing , price);
        ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.dial_fragment, callingScreenFragment, CALLING_FRAGMENT_TAG);

        dialerFragment = (DialerFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(DIALER_FRAGMENT_TAG);

        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);

            ft.addToBackStack(DIALER_FRAGMENT_TAG);


        ft.commit();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation1, R.anim.animation2);

    }
```

**BACKPRESS:**

```
  @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
Log.e("back press called ",""+getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount());
dialerFragment = (DialerFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(DIALER_FRAGMENT_TAG);
if (dialerFragment!=null&&dialerFragment.isVisible()) {
// add your code here
Log.e("dialer fragment","dialer fragment ");
dialerFragment.onBackPress();
}
else {

callingScreenFragment = (CallingScreenFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(CALLING_FRAGMENT_TAG);
if (callingScreenFragment!=null&&callingScreenFragment.isVisible()) {

Log.e("calling  fragment", "calling fragment ");

callingScreenFragment.onBackPress(fromNotification);

}
else {
recentDetailFragment = (RecentDetailFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(LOG_DETAILS_FRAGMENT_TAG);
if (recentDetailFragment!=null&&recentDetailFragment.isVisible()) {
Log.e("recent   fragment","recent fragment ");
recentDetailFragment.onBackPress();
}
else {
super.onBackPressed();
}
}

}
```

**LOGS:**

```
 02-05 17:17:04.967  10280-10280/com.myapp E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.transition.Transition', referenced from method android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21.addTargets
    02-05 17:17:04.967  10280-10280/com.myapp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 1450 (Landroid/transition/Transition;) in Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentTransitionCompat21;
    02-05 17:17:04.967  10280-10280/com.myapp E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.transition.Transition', referenced from method android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21.addTransitionTargets
    02-05 17:17:04.967  10280-10280/com.myapp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 1450 (Landroid/transition/Transition;) in Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentTransitionCompat21;
    02-05 17:17:04.967  10280-10280/com.myapp E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.transition.Transition', referenced from method android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21.beginDelayedTransition
    02-05 17:17:04.967  10280-10280/com.myapp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 1450 (Landroid/transition/Transition;) in Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentTransitionCompat21;
    02-05 17:17:04.967  10280-10280/com.myapp E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.transition.Transition', referenced from method android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21.captureExitingViews
    02-05 17:17:04.967  10280-10280/com.myapp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 1450 (Landroid/transition/Transition;) in Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentTransitionCompat21;
    02-05 17:17:04.967  10280-10280/com.myapp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 12194: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.isTransitionGroup ()Z
    02-05 17:17:04.967  10280-10280/com.myapp E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.transition.Transition', referenced from method android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21.cleanupTransitions
    02-05 17:17:04.967  10280-10280/com.myapp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 1450 (Landroid/transition/Transition;) in Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentTransitionCompat21;
    02-05 17:17:04.967  10280-10280/com.myapp E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.transition.Transition', referenced from method android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21.cloneTransition
    02-05 17:17:04.967  10280-10280/com.myapp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 1450 (Landroid/transition/Transition;) in Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentTransitionCompat21;
    02-05 17:17:04.977  10280-10280/com.myapp E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.transition.Transition', referenced from method android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21.excludeTarget
    02-05 17:17:04.977  10280-10280/com.myapp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 1450 (Landroid/transition/Transition;) in Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentTransitionCompat21;
    02-05 17:17:04.977  10280-10280/com.myapp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 12022: Landroid/view/View;.getTransitionName ()Ljava/lang/String;
    02-05 17:17:04.977  10280-10280/com.myapp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 12022: Landroid/view/View;.getTransitionName ()Ljava/lang/String;
    02-05 17:17:04.977  10280-10280/com.myapp E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.transition.Transition', referenced from method android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21.mergeTransitions
    02-05 17:17:04.977  10280-10280/com.myapp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 1450 (Landroid/transition/Transition;) in Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentTransitionCompat21;
    02-05 17:17:04.977  10280-10280/com.myapp E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.transition.Transition', referenced from method android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21.removeTargets
    02-05 17:17:04.977  10280-10280/com.myapp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 1450 (Landroid/transition/Transition;) in Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentTransitionCompat21;
    02-05 17:17:04.977  10280-10280/com.myapp E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.transition.Transition', referenced from method android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21.setEpicenter
    02-05 17:17:04.977  10280-10280/com.myapp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 1450 (Landroid/transition/Transition;) in Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentTransitionCompat21;
    02-05 17:17:04.977  10280-10280/com.myapp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/transition/Transition;)
            02-05 17:17:04.977  10280-10280/com.myapp W/dalvikvm﹕ Unable to resolve superclass of Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentTransitionCompat21$3; (1449)
            02-05 17:17:04.977  10280-10280/com.myapp W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentTransitionCompat21$3;' failed
    02-05 17:17:04.977  10280-10280/com.myapp E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21$3', referenced from method android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21.setSharedElementEpicenter
    02-05 17:17:04.977  10280-10280/com.myapp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 422 (Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentTransitionCompat21$3;) in Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentTransitionCompat21;
    02-05 17:17:04.987  10280-10280/com.myapp W/dalvikvm﹕ Unable to resolve superclass of Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentTransitionCompat21$1; (1449)
            02-05 17:17:04.987  10280-10280/com.myapp W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentTransitionCompat21$1;' failed
    02-05 17:17:04.987  10280-10280/com.myapp W/dalvikvm﹕ Unable to resolve superclass of Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentTransitionCompat21$3; (1449)
            02-05 17:17:04.987  10280-10280/com.myapp W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentTransitionCompat21$3;' failed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is due to bugs in the `android.support.v4` library which have not yet been resolved (as of the date of this answer).

Essentially, the support library is using API level 19 and 21 APIs, even when running on devices that do not have sufficiently high API levels. This is a very serious (and even shocking) bug, since entire purpose of the Android support libraries is to insulate apps from API level differences!

In your case, you are apparently running on a device with an API level lower than 19, which is when the entire [android.transition](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/package-summary.html) package was introduced.

Related Android issues are: [77670](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77670) and [89244](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=89244). You may want to visit those issue and star them, and/or add a new issue.

Comment: I have this issue on a device running API Level 19 (Android 4.4.2).

Comment: Your log shows that `android.transiiton.Transaction`, which was introduced in API Level 19, could not be found. That should mean that the runtime environment is below level 19. If you just temporarily explicitly use the `Transition` class in your code, does that cause an exception?